# Filter selection in Simple Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, simple-form

I have this code in my form :

```
guidances/new.html.erb
```

> ```
> <%= f.association :employee_department, as: :select %>
> <%= f.input :guidance_supervisor do %>
>   <%= f.select :guidance_supervisor, 
>   Employee.where('guidance_supervisor' => true).map(&:full_name) %>
> <% end %>
> ```

and when selecting a department I need to make the employees who belongs to that department appears, I'm using simple_form , what is the way to make this happen ?

Comment: write active record query out side view page and access it using variable.

Comment: could you write in code ?

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use dynamic drop-down concept. You can see the following post for dynamic drop down in rails:
[Dynamic drop down in rails.](http://gkunwar1.wordpress.com/2013/05/06/rails-dynamic-dropdown/)